# How to Get the Coordinates of a Touch Gesture on a PKCanvasView using PencilKit? Swift 5 & Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pencilkit

*NOTE that I looked a lot everywhere but couldn't find a solution.*

Using the **Storyboard**, I have a **ViewController**, with a **View** (UIView) and a **Subview** (PKCanvasView) where I want to use **PencilKit** to draw on the latter.

_

**My objectives** are:

1. **Draw** only on this *PKCanvasView*
2. Get the **coordinates** in real time of where I'm drawing on the *PKCanvasView*

**My results**:

1. **I can draw** on the *PKCanvasView* only if I start from this view, and I can only draw within the frame of this *PKCanvasView*. That's good.
2. **I can only manage** to get the coordinates of where I'm touching the screen **IF** I start the gesture on the *UIView*. **BUT Not** if I touch the *PKCanvasView* first.

**My problem**:

How do I get the coordinates of where I'm drawing on the PKCanvasView?

–

**Below is my code**:

```
import UIKit
import PencilKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelText: UILabel! //Label object to display the coordinates

    @IBOutlet weak var canvasView: PKCanvasView! //Subview to draw on

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        canvasView.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: .black, width: 10)
    }

    // MARK: FUNCTIONS //
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touches.forEach { (touch) in
            updateGagues(with: touch)
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touches.forEach { (touch) in
            updateGagues(with: touch)
        }
    }

    private func updateGagues(with touch: UITouch) {
        let location = touch.preciseLocation(in: view)
        labelText.text = location.debugDescription
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I recently experienced the same problem of getting touch coordinates from my PKCanvasView. To do this, I created a subclass of PKCanvasView and overrode the touchesBegan function:

```swift
class Canvas: PKCanvasView {

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    touches.forEach { touch in
      print("touch location \(touch.location(in: self))")
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I haven’t tried this yet but presumably the canvas view  needs the touch methods to actually do the drawing, if you override them, then wouldn’t all that functionality be lost?

Comment: Just add: super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event) before your own implementation, then the inherited functionality will be called as well.